# How to filter an array that is part of ObservableCollection in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, filter, collections

I have an `ObservableCollection` of `AcquiredDateGroup` objects called Items. One of the properties of `AcquiredDateGroup` is an array of `Feature` objects called features.

I have rather complicated tree view that binds to the ObservableCollection. Attributes of `AcquiredDateGroup` are used for grouping and the Feature array is used for the final leaves in the tree. I want to filter the features array based on one of it's properties, lets say `IsSelected`  but so far all the examples I have found filter the parent `ObservableCollection` using things like CollectionView and CollectionViewSource.

Is there a way to filter this array directly?

AcquiredDateGroup class

```
 class AcquiredDateGroup : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Feature[] features { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
        public DateTime acquired { get; set; }
        public string date
        {
            get
            {
                return acquired.Date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> Items
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Feature class

```
public class Feature
{
    public _Links1 _links { get; set; }
    public object[] _permissions { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

very simplified view excerpt. :

```
    <TreeView Name="SearchResults" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" IsEnabled="{Binding TreeEnabled}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Feature}">
     <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Visibility="{Binding IsSelected , Converter={StaticResource SelectCheckIconVisibiltyConverter }}"  IsEnabled="{Binding _permissions, Converter={StaticResource PermissionsConverter}}"  Margin="5,0,0,0" Focusable="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="Select" Tag="{Binding Path=id}">
                                    </CheckBox>
```

MVVM excerpt:

```
private ObservableCollection<Model.AcquiredDateGroup> _items;
public ObservableCollection<Model.AcquiredDateGroup> Items
{
    get
    {
        if (_items == null)
        {
            _items = new ObservableCollection<Model.AcquiredDateGroup>();
        }
        return _items;
    }
    set
    {
        _items = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}
```

Comment: If `Feature[]` is binding to `XAML` then consider changing it to `ObservableCollection` that way you can filter it in the `View` with less effort.

Comment: I'm not clear about your end goal? Do you want to display items in the `Items` list if _all_ items in the corresponding `Feature.IsSelected=true`?

Comment: @abin I didn't think of that, I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: @sach the end result will be to filter the tree based on the permissions object. This object has a host of properties that are manipulated in different parts of the view.

Comment: @Dowlers I'm still not clear about your filter criteria. You want to filter the `Items` list right? But each `AcquiredDateGroup` has an array of `Feature`, which in turn contain `IsSelected` property. So do you want to select an item from the `Items` list if the `IsSelected` property of _all_ of it's `Feature` array are also true? Otherwise, what if only some are `true` and others `false`?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you haven't quite figured out what your requirements are, and also your `TreeView` control's `ItemTemplate` isn't quite set right.

I'm using a trimmed down version of your classes for brevity.

```
public class AcquiredDateGroup
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
}
```

Imagine this is what my data looks like:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<AcquiredDateGroup>
{
    new AcquiredDateGroup() 
    { 
        ID = 1, 
        Features = new ObservableCollection<Feature>() 
        {
            new Feature() { Name = "A", IsSelected = true }, 
            new Feature() { Name = "B", IsSelected = false }, 
            new Feature() { Name = "C", IsSelected = true } 
        } 
    },
    new AcquiredDateGroup() 
    { 
        ID = 2, 
        Features = new ObservableCollection<Feature>() 
        { 
            new Feature() { Name = "D", IsSelected = false }, 
            new Feature() { Name = "E", IsSelected = true }, 
            new Feature() { Name = "F", IsSelected = false } 
        } 
    },
};
```

Now in your `XAML` you'll need to set a `TreeView.ItemTemplate` and a `DataTemplate` to display your data.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Features}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

And this gives you an output like so:

[image]

---

### EDIT

Say you want to display only the `IsSelected == true` items in `Features` list in your tree view. Then you should consider doing the filtering in your `ViewModel` instead of the `View`, as keeping your `View` and `ViewModel` decoupled is the ideal `MVVM` design.

So I'd alter the `AcquiredDateGroup` class to add a new `get` only property which returns the items in `Features` list where `IsSelected` is `true`.

```
public class AcquiredDateGroup
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> FeaturesIsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return Features.Where(x => x.IsSelected == true).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `XAML` you can bind to this new property.

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding FeaturesIsChecked}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Now you can display only the items that have `IsSelected` set to `true`:

[image]